# Angular js application, optimized with r.js is not working

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, r.js

Angular JS application is working fine, but nothing is appearing when optimized with r.js.
Here is the source code

in **index.html**

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="libs/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
baseUrl: '../',
waitSeconds: 200,
paths: {
    'appBootstrap': 'scripts/appBootstrap',
    'angular': 'libs/angular/angular',
    'ngRoute': 'libs/angular/angular-route',
    'ngMessages': 'libs/angular/angular-messages',
    'jQuery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.1',
    'bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.1',
    'pace': 'libs/others/pace',
    'toastr': 'libs/others/toastr',
    'routes': 'scripts/routes',
    'text': 'libs/requirejs/text',
    'ngTable': 'libs/angular/ng-table.min',
    'app': 'scripts/app'
},
deps: (function () {
    //return [ "../output/app.min" ]; // For Production
    return ["appBootstrap"]; //For Development
})(),

shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'ngRoute': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'ngMessages': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jQuery']
    },
    'ui.bootstrap': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'toastr': {
        deps: ['jQuery'],
        exports: 'toastr'
    },
    'pace': {
        exports: ['pace']
    },
    'ngTable': {
        deps: ['angular']
    }
}
```

});

Here I am switching app bootstrap and optimized file based on development environment( You can see in deps function)

**App bootstrap file:**

```
define(['app', 'routes'], function (app, routes) {
    try {
            // bootstrap the app manually
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in bootstraping the root"+ e.message);
        console.error(e.stack);
    }  
});
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
define(['angular',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngTable',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'controllers/controllers',
        'directives/directives',
        'filters/filters',
        'factories/factories',
        'constants/constants'],
    function (angular) {
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute',
                                         'ngMessages',
                                         'ngTable',
                                         'ui.bootstrap',
                                         'app.controllers',
                                         'app.directives',
                                         'app.filters',
                                         'app.factories',
                                         'app.constants']);
        app.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $location, apiCallFactory) {
                    ......
        });
        return app;
    });
```

**routes.js**

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';
     return app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/adminHome', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/adminHome.html',
                    controller: 'adminHomeCtrl'
                })
                .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginCtrl'
                })
                .when('/profile', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/userProfile.html',
                    controller: 'userProfileCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/login'
                });

        });
});
```

**r.js input file (optimizedjs.js)**

```
({
    baseUrl: '../',
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        'appBootstrap': 'scripts/appBootstrap',
        'angular': 'libs/angular/angular',
        'ngRoute': 'libs/angular/angular-route',
        'ngMessages': 'libs/angular/angular-messages',
        'jQuery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.1',
        'bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.1',
        'pace': 'libs/others/pace',
        'toastr': 'libs/others/toastr',
        'routes': 'scripts/routes',
        'text': 'libs/requirejs/text',
        'ngTable': 'libs/angular/ng-table.min',
        'app': 'scripts/app'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'ngRoute': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'ngMessages': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jQuery']
        },
        'ui.bootstrap': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'toastr': {
            deps: ['jQuery'],
            exports: 'toastr'
        },
        'pace': {
            exports: ['pace']
        },
        'ngTable': {
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    },
    stubModules: ['text'],
    name: "appBootstrap",
    out: "../output/app.min.js"
})
```

I am using `node r.js -o optimizejs.js` to get the optimized file.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on minimizing your angular code, make sure you declare your dependency injection according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Example:

`return app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {`

to

`return app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {`

Or you can look into [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to do that automatically when you build the code.